# Django 'apps.get_model' returns error but works properly

Tags: django

I use variable `model_name` which is being sent with ajax call in order to understand what model instance should be changed. Then I am getting model with `apps.get_model` and receive an error which looks like this `LookupError: App 'dashboard' doesn't have a '' model.`. Despite that, data is being changed properly. It is correctly displayed in DB and on the page itself. I double checked and it is correctly displayed in console log, so server receives valid data.

My view class:

```
class UpdateStaticFieldsAndSelectElements(View):

    def post(self, request):

        new_value = request.POST.get('new_value', '')
        model_name = request.POST.get('modell_name', '')
        model_field_name = request.POST.get('model_field_name', '')
        model_instance_id = request.POST.get('model_instance_id', '')

        if model_name == 'User':
            update_object_model = apps.get_model('users', model_name)
        else:
            update_object_model = apps.get_model('dashboard', model_name)
        update_object = get_object_or_404(update_object_model, id=model_instance_id)
        setattr(update_object, model_field_name, new_value)
        update_object.save()

        data = {'object_text': getattr(update_object, model_field_name)}

        return JsonResponse(data)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Likely it should be `request.POST.get('model_name', '')` instead of `request.POST.get('modell_name', '')`?

Comment: Typo?: modell_name

Comment: But nevertheless, this looks rather unsafe. People can try to use this to obtain data out of the database. For example by binary searching on data in related model objects names. Please don't do this.

Comment: Unfortunatelly synthax is not a problem. I just don't get why it throws an error but works fine after all. @WillemVanOnsem Thanks, I will consider this.